# Can't create AWS Lambda function from console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am unable to create an AWS Lambda function from console. The `Create Function` button keeps rotating but unable to create a function.

I am using default `permissions` and `Advanced Settings`

[image]

I don't see error message at all. What could have been wrong here?

Comment: The "Last fetched 53 years ago" message is a bit worrying. Can you try from a different browser, and perhaps across another network connection (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone)? If it was a permissions error, it would say so.

Comment: I used two different browser Chrome and FireFox. Same issue in both browser.

Comment: Can you check whether the clock on your computer is set correctly? I know that there can be errors if it is out of range too much, and that "53 years" has me concerned. You could also look in your browser console (if you know how to access the browser's Developer Console) to see what errors might be displaying.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to permissions. Check the permissions, specially, If you have the `iam:CreateRole` that is necessary to automatically create the role need to run the lambda function.

Also see this similar [post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUK04Bor0PTTK1NodWWmvaVg/create-function-lambda-permission-issue).

Comment: I have given administrative access to IAM user and used policy for role from [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html) Still not able to create lambda-function